# Shell Script: See disk usage on a map with a subfolder+files

Tags: shell, directory, subdirectory

I would want to make a script that shows the disk usage for a folder with a subfolder with files.

The directory looks like this: `/home/Joel/map/map2` and in `map2` I have some files.

I tried `du -h /home/Joel/map -d 3` but it only shows `map` and `map2` but not the files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From `man du` :

> du [OPTION]... [FILE]...
>
> -a, --all
>
> write counts for all files, not just directories
>
> -d, --max-depth=N
>
> print the total for a directory (or file, with --all) only if it is N or fewer levels below the command line argument; --max-depth=0 is the same as --summarize

So you only have to do `du -ah -d 3 /home/Joel/map`